# background-image gets padded in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have a XHTML 1.0 Transitional web page with following main table:

```
<table>
<tr>
<!-- header -->
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="left"><!-- menu --></td>
<td class="content"><!-- content and header iamge --></td>
<td class="right"><!-- other stuff --></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<!-- footer -->
</tr>
</table>
```

The CSS looks like this:

```
#content {
    width:100%;

    vertical-align:top;
    background-color:white;

    /* desired padding of the content */
    padding-right:10px;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-bottom:10px;

    background-image: url(bilder/pseudo-panorama3.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position: center top;
    padding-top:213px; /* height of the picture + the desired 10px padding to the content */

}
```

The planned behavior is as follows:

[image: Planned behavior]

In Firefox 31, the page shows up as expected:

[image: How it looks in Firefox]

In Internet Explorer 11, there is a space between the background image and the cell-border:

[image: How it looks in IE]

What can I do to remove this space? I already tried [`background-clip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/jj127314%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) , but it didn't work.

The URL of the web page is here: http://www.thrs-heidelberg.de/v2/htdoc/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add this to your table tag..

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">...</table>
```

Give it a try and lets see if you have the same issue.

By default tables have a default value for cellpadding and cellspacing of 2, even if you dont specify this at all.

with css you can control the padding for each cell, but not the cellspacing.

Edit.

Also try this...

```
#content {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    -o-box-sizing: border-box;
    -khtml-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;

    /* Put the rest of your css here for this class */
}
```

here is the issue...

you have a box with 100px in size (width)
you add 10px in padding (left and right)

you should expect that the box its still 100px, but this is not the case on some browsers.

a total of 20px will be added to your original 100px, so your box will be 120px, this also happens if you add a border.

The way to fix this is to apply to the affected object the previous mentioned css, that will fix the box model issue.

Comment: Thanks. I tried it, but it didn't affect this space.

Comment: Post a jsfiddle, that way I will be able to assist you better

Comment: Thanks for your hints. I built them into my CSS. Probably it will help being compatible with more browsers. I feel a bit embarrassed as I found out that the reason was not the padding, but the fact that the picture was too small. In Internet Explorer, the menus were a bit smaller (probably because of a smaller font), therefore the header image was not wide enough. Coincidentally, the missing size looked nearly like the padding I used, so I thought it was a padding issue.

Comment: Shall I mark your answer as solution or should this question be marked as invalid?

Comment: I don't know, but you dont need to specify a width value of 100% to your #content element, there is no need, he is not the only TD, and  if you want to let that #content to have what ever space its available from the table, just dont specify the with at all